# I want to get the text in center of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a website and I just need help to align the text in centre of the page and the picture on the left like so but it doesn't work out. I want it like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/hdyx7r6fdajpows/Untitled.png?dl=0

```html
<div style="text-align: left;">
  <img src="3.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="300" width="200">

  <center> 
     <pre> <h2 style="color: black;"> hello </h2> </pre> 
  </center>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `center` tag is deprecated in HTML5.

If you want to use inline-style then use the following code:

```html
<div>
  <img src="3.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="300" width="200" >
  <h2 style="color: black; margin-top: 150px; display:inline-block; position: absolute; width: 80%; text-align: center;"> hello </h2>
</div>
```

If you do not want to use inline-style then use the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <img src="3.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="300" width="200" >
  <h2> hello </h2>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
h2 {
  color: black; 
  margin-top: 150px; 
  display:inline-block; 
  position: absolute; 
  width: 80%; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

Note: If you have many `<h2>` elements in the page, then define class or id to avoid applying style for all of them.

Comment: I mean something like this. https://www.dropbox.com/s/hdyx7r6fdajpows/Untitled.png?dl=0 Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

It's best to separate the css code from the html code.

```
div img {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}
div h2 { text-align: center; }
```

html code:

```
<div>
  <img src="3.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
  <h2>hello</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use CSS to do this, instead of trying to style, you can use `<center></center`. But if you really want to style it then add this line on css:`margin: 0 auto;`
This will work!

EDIT: You cannot use css or center tags while you use `<pre></pre>`, because pre makes everything `Normal` so it wont work with `<pre></pre>`!!!

Comment: <center> is deprecated - it's best to use CSS to center elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: I understand, as i said, if you really want to use CSS then add line: `margin: 0 auto;`